# Cantonese pingshu?

Tags: cantonese

I'm trying to find a good Cantonese *pingshu* performer. I would really like to find something akin to [Li Boqing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Boqing) (李伯清) speaking in Chengduese or [Wu Wen](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%B4%E6%96%87/85214) (吴文) speaking in Chongqingese. Something similar to [Guo Degang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guo_Degang)'s (郭德纲) performances would work as well.

Some similarities these actors share:

- Born no later than '73
- [Old-school](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%81%E6%B4%BE%E5%8F%91%E9%9F%B3) (老派) speakers
- Stand-up/storytelling performers
- Popular in the ~90s/00s

I think there's a good sweet spot of speakers born in the 40s who did well in the 90s and managed avoiding more modern-官话 corruption.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For Cantonese, you can search [講古人](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk017fTxes_-sUXBPGy6CUsV5ILDvmQ:1617424267210&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=%E8%91%97%E5%90%8D%E8%AC%9B%E5%8F%A4%E4%BA%BA&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxl5f3nuHvAhWNW80KHagCAYMQjJkEegQIERAB&biw=1596&bih=752)(story teller)

*講古佬 is a more casual/ colloquial term for it*

- 講 means 'talk'
- 古 here doesn't mean 'ancient'. It is short for '古仔' (故事; tales) which include recent events and fictional story

Since 講古 is strictly a Cantonese term, the people you find on the search would all be Cantonese 评书 or 评话.

Meanwhile, [説書人](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AA%AA%E6%9B%B8%E4%BA%BA#Chinese) is a more literary term for 講古人/ 講古佬

Also, you can look at [楝篤笑](https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A3%9F%E7%AF%A4%E7%AC%91) (Stand-up comedy) performer

- 楝篤 =  stand vertical
- 笑 = 講笑話 (telling jokes)

Comment: Could you recommend any specific performers?